# Для чего применяются и на что влияют xmlns и xmlns:xlink в svg?

Tags: html, вёрстка, xml, svg, xmlparser

Чем отличаются? Обязательно ли их использовать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Рассмотрим вопрос на практическом примере, где в шапке SVG файла нет объявления пространства имён  `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
<symbol id="rect">
<rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" rx="15"  />
</symbol>

 <use xlink:href="#rect" style="fill:purple;" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" style="fill:gold;" />
</svg>
```

1. Если этот SVG код добавлен в HTML, то современные браузеры, включая `Edge` и `IE11` выполнят его без сообщения об ошибке.  Для примера, сниппет этого сайта вполне успешно воспроизводит различной сложности svg код, без добавления пространства имен xlink.
2. Если этот SVG код сохранить, как файл с расширением - `*.svg` и запустить его в браузере, то получим сообщение об ошибке:

### Chrome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Firefox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если указать вместо  `xlink:href="#rect` только `href="#rect` сообщения об ошибке парсера XML в этих браузерах не будет.

Почему так происходит?  **SVG2**, в готовящемся к публикации стандарте W3C `xlink:href` объявлен не желательным, устаревшим (`depricate`)

Но слишком долго внедряется этот стандарт и некоторые браузеры поторопились внедрить его в свои движки.

Но safari, например **не принимает** `href`, для него валидна только `xlink:href`  запись svg версии 1.2

### Что делать, чтобы ваш SVG код был рабочим во всех браузерах?

Пока браузерные войны не закончились, пока не внедрён стандарт SVG2 лучше указывать дополнительно и "ссылочное" пространства имен `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`.
Можно сохранить для себя шаблон шапки SVG файла и начинать с него создание нового SVG кода:

```
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
       </svg>
```

Для кроссбраузерного решения можно писать или старую форму записи `xlink:href`
или комбинированный вариант:

```
<use xlink:href="#rect" href="#rect"" style="fill:purple;" />
```

Comment: То есть по сути, оба варианта (xmlns и xmlns:xlink), и у вас тут ещё есть третий вариант - xlink:href не имеют особой разницы между собой (разве что есть более устаревшие варианты записи). Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @eva Вы правильно поняли, что есть устаревшие записи и записи в новом стандарте SVG2. Но он ещё не принят. Поэтому, чтобы не было проблем с кроссбраузерностью ваших приложений, пишите, как указано в конце ответа. Перед этим был просто анализ возможных вариантов

Comment: Раньше мне думалось, что xlink:href используется не для указания пространства имён, а просто для вставки ссылки

Comment: спасибо за объяснение

Comment: @Eva xlink:href или просто href  для указания ссылки на объект см. самый последний пример `<use xlink:href="#rect" href="#rect"" style="fill:purple;" />` а пространство имен, чтобы заработала ссылка    `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

Comment: Ага, хорошо. Не совсем ещё понимаю вот что - чем отличаются xmlns и xmlns:xlink? И то, и то это пространство имён? Хmlns  указывает просто на то, что употребляется пространство имён, а xmlns:xlink говорит о том, что к этой странице прикреплен xml? Как? Столько информации прочитано, но до сих пор непонятно

Comment: @eva Вас вводит в заблуждение обилие одинаковых букв в этих двух терминах. Ещё раз 1. `xlink:href="#rect"`  это ссылка на объект svg -  rect, circle, gradient, mask **внутри тела программы svg кода** - которые были определены раньше внутри секций `<symbol>` или `<defs>`  2. `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` пишется один раз в **шапке** svg файла

Answer (score 4):

xlink в svg нужен, чтобы делать ссылки (как href) из svg:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLink

В каждом svg -- не нужен.

svg -- стандарт основанный на xml (оформляется по правилам xml).
xlink -- другой стандарт основанный на xml.

xmlns... -- это xml-ное использование пространства имен

`xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` говорит о том, что ниже будет иметься ввиду xlink стандарт, который предложен организацией w3.

Вася имеет право придумать свой способ `http://vasya.tk/xlink` для описания котиков (который основан на xml).
Коля имеет право придумать свой стандарт для описания зоопарка, и в одном из описаний сослаться на способ Васи:

```
<zoo xmlns:xlink="http://vasya.tk/xlink">
  <xlink:cat xlink:food="fish" />
  ...
```

И все в демократичном мире xml все поймут, какой где xlink имелся ввиду.